# Remove input value

Tags: jquery

I want to remove "Log In " text from here

```
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In">
```

Thanks

Comment: select `Log In` and press `delete`

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="">`

Comment: What is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: `document.getElementById('wp-submit').value = '';`

Comment: @SheikhHeera  I wanted a Jquery solution .A boy who can type can do what you said but I am new in Jquery  so I sought help

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question that you want to clear the value of your text box using `jQuery`, anyways, you got it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select it with `#id` selector and delete its value

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wp-submit').val('');
});
```